# C2228: Error with TCP asio server

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm making a TCP server by using the boost::asio library.

At this moment, I have working it with a code like this:
*Note:This is a testing server for non-profit.*

```
    int main(){
        const int SERVER_PORT = 60000;

        try{
            ...
            //declare the io_service, endpoint, acceptor and socket
            ...
            {
                acceptor.accept(socket);
                boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message));
                boost::asio::streambuf received;
                boost::asio::read_until(socket, received, "\r\n");
                ...
                //all server operations
                ...
                }
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::cerr << "Exception " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Now, I wan't to improve the code and I started by organizing my code by functions like this:

```
    void session(){
        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message));
        boost::asio::streambuf received;
        boost::asio::read_until(socket, received, "\r\n");
        ...
        //All server operations
        ...
    }

    void server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, const int SERVER_PORT){
        ...
        //declare the io_service, endpoint, acceptor and socket
        ...
        session();//Call Session
    }


    int main(){
        const int SERVER_PORT = 60000;
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        server(io_service, SERVER_PORT);

        return 0;
    }
```

My problem is that with the functions, it doesn't compile.
I have the Visual Studio compilation error: C2228

> error C2228:The operand to the left of the period .read_some is not a
>   class, structure, or union
>
> error C2228:The operand to the left of the period .write_some is not a
>   class, structure, or union

I don't found how to fix this problem.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT: SOLUTION BASED ON THE ANSWER**

Unless socket is a global vairable, void session() is not valid.
The good one is:

```
void session(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
```

Thanks very much to **Orrkid**

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that attempts to call `read_some` or `write_some`. Nobody will be able to help you unless you post the code where the error happens.

Comment: Hi, `read_some` and `write_some` are inside the library Boost::Asio.
For example, `read_some` is inside `read_until.hpp`, isn't part of my code.

Comment: You are not calling either of those in the example code you posted and the problem is how you are calling these not how these are implemented. No one can help until you show the code that calls these.

Comment: But in all my code I don't call this two..
I think that it comes from the `read_until` and the `write`, because if I comment these two I don't have any error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is socket defined? sounds like it isn't properly defined causing the write and read_until functions to throw the error.

read_some and write_some are called inside the write and read_until

(edit) looking at your code, unless socket is a global vairable, how is it getting passed into your session function, I see where you commented that you will declare them in your server function, but unless you have omitted more code from the example, looks like void session() is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a socket object ,The name of this object is conflict with Socket under windows,so you need to modify this name.